# Add slide color overlay over posts on RecyclerView

Tags: android, events, android-recyclerview, slide

I want to create something similar in my app so users can react via slides to RecyclerViews viewholders, and then add event listeners to them. How would I implement this?
I created a simple illustration with motion graphics.

[image: Demonstartion]

Answer (score 0):

See this [ItemTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html)  and especially  `onChildDraw()` callback method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But isn't this method useful for removing those items from the list? I want the viewholders to actually be in the background and not the foreground as shown at the gif above.

Comment: with `onChildDraw()` method you can change background of recyclerview element with swipe animation just like your example

Comment: But I don't want the background to change, the recyclerview might be an image. What I want is a transparent view to overlay it with a swipe, and then fade it out. (This feature is supposed to be similar to Instagram's double tap to like)

Answer (score 0):

I could reach something similar to what your are asking using ClipDrawable.

Solution is below:

**res/values/colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- need colors with alpha.. Not full transparent and not full opaque -->
    <color name="left_to_right_color">#AA008800</color>
    <color name="right_to_left_color">#AACC2200</color>
</resources>
```

**main_activity_layout.xml**

I added a View exactly above the ImageView. This way, I control the background of View... If you try to control the background of ImageView, the animation will happen behind the Icon...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/YOU_PICTURE" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/imageview_surface_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        View view = findViewById(R.id.imageview_surface_view);
        view.setOnTouchListener(new MyCustomTouchListener());
    }

    private class MyCustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        private static final int THRESHOLD_VALUE = 100;
        private static final int UNKOWN = 0;
        private static final int LEFT_TO_RIGHT = 1;
        private static final int RIGHT_TO_LEFT = 2;
        private int direction = UNKOWN;
        private int startX;
        private int endX;
        private ClipDrawable clipDrawable;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            int action = motionEvent.getAction();
            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                startX = (int) motionEvent.getX();
                endX = (int) (view.getWidth() - view.getX());
                return true;
            } else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                AlphaAnimation fadeOutAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
                fadeOutAnimation.setDuration(300);
                fadeOutAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        // Do nothing
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        if(clipDrawable != null)
                            clipDrawable.setLevel(0);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                });
                view.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
                direction = UNKOWN;
                return true;
            } else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                if(direction == UNKOWN) {
                    if(motionEvent.getX() > startX) {
                        if(startX < (view.getX() + THRESHOLD_VALUE)) {
                            direction = LEFT_TO_RIGHT;
                            clipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.left_to_right_color),
                                    Gravity.START, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
                            view.setBackground(clipDrawable);
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else if (startX > (endX - THRESHOLD_VALUE)) {
                        direction = RIGHT_TO_LEFT;
                        clipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.right_to_left_color),
                                Gravity.END, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
                        view.setBackground(clipDrawable);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                } else if (clipDrawable != null){
                    if(direction == LEFT_TO_RIGHT)
                        clipDrawable.setLevel((int) motionEvent.getX() * 10000 / endX);
                    else
                        clipDrawable.setLevel(10000 - (int) motionEvent.getX() * 10000 / endX);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this code may help you to find what do you want

Comment: All is excellent except that part of the animation. If you lift your finger, the overlay is gone. I need to find a way to make it slide till the end of the screen with a swipe.

Comment: After ending the swype, the view must remain colored? I think I need to add some if/else conditions were action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

Comment: Exactly the opposite, I want the user to swipe from left to right and not just drag it from the start to the end. And then, after the ClipDrawable covers the screen, fade it out. I want it to be as comfortable as the double-tap to like feature on Instagram if you know it. (Also, imagine my GIF with the finger starting to swipe from the center of the view for example.

Comment: Ok... Give some minutes and I'll update the answer :)

Comment: I liked the animation but still (sorry for bothering), the kind of effect I want to achieve is as if you had a transparent ViewPager with tabs over the Image. The first tab will be green, the second one is completely transparent and the third is red. Then, you "switch between tabs" but actually instead of keeping the color, you fade out back to the 2nd tab. It just that ViewPager or maybe even Navigation Drawer has that feel of resistance to your finger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117838/discussion-between-ofir-and-guilherme-p).

Comment: @Ofir Sorry... but I'm not able to help you more... really sorry for that.. Hope my code may help you to achieve what you want!

Comment: No problem! You did a lot more than enough, thanks a lot!